# How do I change the suffix of all files that contain a specific string

Tags: linux, grep, find

I want to find all *.xml files that have a particular DOCTYPE and change the suffix from .xml to .dita.

I can list the files doing this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.xml' -exec grep --files-with-matches '<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA' {} +
```

but I'm not clear about piping this into an mv command that will do the desired rename.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803296/modifying-replace-string-in-xargs which may be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Modifying replace string in xargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803296/modifying-replace-string-in-xargs) from @betabandido:

Try to add `| xargs -n 1 -i sh -c 'echo mv $1 ${1%.xml}.dita' -- {}`, if output looks OK, remove the `echo`, assuming `sh` is in fact `bash` since tagged with `linux`.